# How can i access unicode symbols in Adobe Firework reliably

Tags: unicode, symbols, fireworks

I am trying to get some of the more abstract math symbols and utilize them in Adobe Fireworks with limited success. I use the character map feature of windows and cut and paste. It does not work for most symbols. Is there another option?

Examples not working for me

∲   ∯    ⊆

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Adobe forum seems to suggest changing your font to Arial Unicode MS:
https://forums.adobe.com/thread/661251

For myself, Character Map seems to work reliably, although I am using "FontAwesome", not mathematical symbols.

You can also try directly typing the character code using Alt + [type numerical code of font].

Hope this helps!